# Как получить указатель на экземпляр активити или фрагмента из другого класса?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Собственно, суть в заголовке. Желательно с примером, заранее благодарю

Comment: Маловато, для сути. Распишите более подробно, что? зачем? куда?

Comment: @xAqweRx
Есть класс, наследуемый от fragment. В нём есть не статический метод. Необходимо вызвать этот метод из другого класса. Гугл насоветовал сделать это через указатель на существующий экземпляр фрагмента. Как мне его получить?

Comment: Ну если у вас есть доступ к активити в которой находиться фргамент,- то можете в активити сделать getter в котором будете возвращать нужный фрагмент

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код - код активити и фрагмента. Тогда будет иметь смысл. Иначе - смотрите коментарий выше.

Comment: Каким образом связаны Ваши класс и фрагмент? Может проще через интерфейс будет.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что хотите. Если нужна обратится к методу из любого места то ПРИМЕР:

Вызов:

```
ActionIntentUtil.CallPhone(activity, "8805000000");
```

`ActionIntentUtil` - название класса где находится метод

Где `activity` можно использовать `this`,  `((имя активности) getActivity())`, `getActivity()`, `view.getContext()`

Сам метод:

```
public static void CallPhone(Context context, String number) {
    try {
        Uri address = Uri.parse("tel:"+number);
        Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
        context.startActivity(openlink);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, apps, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Если вызывает в том же классе где метод то можно убрать `static` и `ActionIntentUtil`